# How to get table height in PDFsharp?

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using PDFsharp to generate PDF documents and these documents (invoices) contain tables.

Is there any way to determine the height of a table?  I need to know the height as VAT and Total tables have to be positioned at the bottom of the page.  I don't think a count of the rows would do because product descriptions can get wrapped resulting in increased row height for some rows

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the problem.
I think you want to create a table that spans several pages, but you need a summary at the bottom of each page.

Sounds like you're using MigraDoc, not PDFsharp.

MigraDoc works similar to Word: you define the contents, MigraDoc cares for the pagebreaks.

Tables with sum rows at the bottom are not supported.

You can add sum rows and pagebreaks manually. To do this you must estimate how many items fit on one page (taking the length of descriptions into account).